# Windows Server 2008 R2 Reports PerfNet Error EventID 2002

Tags: windows-server-2008

0

Unable to open the Redirector service performance object. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the status code.

Comment: That's an error message. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Yes it is an error message my question is When this error message occurred  and how to fix it